# How To replaced the function of WooCommerce plugin using own created custom plugin without using theme function.php

Tags: php, wordpress

Is it possible to override the Woo Commerce template using my own plugin?

If possible, can you provide some tips on how to do this in an easy way?

I am new in this WordPress arena.

Many thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 2):

The normal WooCommerce template loader searches the following locations in order, until a match is found:

1. your theme / template path / template name
2. your theme / template name
3. default path / template name

You can alter this slightly by injecting a search for the template within your own custom plugin (step 3 below), before finally defaulting to the WooCommerce core templates directory:

1. your theme / template path / template name
2. your theme / template name
3. your plugin / woocommerce / template name
4. default path / template name

This can be done by adding the following function and filter to your plugin, which basically duplicates and modifies the behavior of the `woocommerce_locate_template()` function found within `woocommerce-core-functions.php`:

```
function myplugin_plugin_path() {

  // gets the absolute path to this plugin directory

  return untrailingslashit( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) );
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_locate_template', 'myplugin_woocommerce_locate_template', 10, 3 );


function myplugin_woocommerce_locate_template( $template, $template_name, $template_path ) {
  global $woocommerce;

  $_template = $template;

  if ( ! $template_path ) $template_path = $woocommerce->template_url;

  $plugin_path  = myplugin_plugin_path() . '/woocommerce/';

  // Look within passed path within the theme - this is priority
  $template = locate_template(

    array(
      $template_path . $template_name,
      $template_name
    )
  );

  // Modification: Get the template from this plugin, if it exists
  if ( ! $template && file_exists( $plugin_path . $template_name ) )
    $template = $plugin_path . $template_name;

  // Use default template
  if ( ! $template )
    $template = $_template;

  // Return what we found
  return $template;
}
```

With that active you can override core template files by placing them in myplugin/woocommerce/.

For instance, to override `loop/add-to-cart.php`, copy that file to your plugin in the following location: `myplugin/woocommerce/loop/add-to-cart.php` and make your modifications.

The theme will still be able to override it, and all other template files will be loaded from WooCommerce or the default path, as normal.

Source: https://www.skyverge.com/blog/override-woocommerce-template-file-within-a-plugin/

Comment: thank you for the feedback does it affect the woocommerce plugin if I updated the plugin, if yes is there any alternated way without touching the code in woocommerce plugin